# Para que serve a keyword noexcept e quando usar ela?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

O que faz a *keyword* `noexcept` no C++ e em que situação ela devem ser usada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duas formas:

## Atributo especificador

Indica que a função não pode lançar uma exceção, o que permite uma série de otimizações e o compilador entender melhor a semântica. Depois que colocar não pode tirar, faz parte do contrato. use-a sempre que possível. Na verdade até que venha uma nova forma de exceção, em C++20 ou C++23, evite exceções.

Em C++14 era um pouco diferente, mas não considere esta forma, prefira a do C++17.

Veja mais na [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec).

## Operador

Usado essencialmente para metaprogramação/reflexão habilitando seleções e especializações do que compilar conforme o que encontrar. Algo bem mais avançado. É uma forma de consultar durante a compilação se a função não pode lançar exceção.

Veja mais na [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept).